# import vb.net class library to vb6 project

Tags: vb.net, com, vb6, com-interop

I have created a vb.net class library. It is an interface for a storage device. It gives some objects and methods in order to read and write data to the device.

The problem is that a customer has a vb6 application where we want to add the functionality of the class library in order to manipulate the device. i have changed the classes to com classes, checked the com interopt checkbox and registered the library with .net framework 2.0 regasm.exe.

I added the library as reference to a blank vb6 project and created an object.

```
dim t as comlib.obj
```

the object was equal to 'nothing'

when I added:

```
t = new comlib.obj
```

or

```
 t = createobject("comlib.obj")
```

I got the following error:

> run-time error '2147024894 (80070002)': Automation

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read the help on how to format posts and apply it next time. There's absolutely no need to use `<br>` tags.

Comment: It is a common Windows error, "File not found".  Odds are good that is generated because you forgot to use the /codebase option when you used Regasm.exe.  You can use SysInternals' Procmon utility if you have no idea what file might be missing.

Comment: Another possibility is that the COM wrapper might not have been built or registered with x86 or x64 in mind.  I've run into that problem with an old classic ASP application in the past.  It ran in x86 mode, and that required me to build my wrapper using x86 and also register using an x86 version of regasm.exe. Since then, I've gotten in the habit of providing installers/builds for both x86 and x64 and the consumer can choose which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Just dimming a variable doesn't assign it a value (the same as a .NET `private TypeName variableName;`), you need to create it first using `Set T = New Comlib.Obj`.

If you get an error from this, you need to use standard debugging techniques to narrow it down, or maybe post your full error message and someone can advise.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that @Deanna has the solution but if that fails then

I would suggest that you need to look at your constructor in the .NET assembly and make sure this is not throwing any sort of runtime error.

Even if you have an error handler in your New Sub it will not be raised up to the VB6 app.

I have followed a convention to keep my .NET constructor to a bare minimum and then use an additional method the do the construction code (LoadData for example). This way you can have an appropriate error handler. If an error is then thrown - it is raised into VB6 correctly.