# Using CreateObject ActiveX component can't create object w/ Registered Class Library

Tags: vb.net, com, vb6

I have written some classes in visual basic.net and want to use them in a visual basic 6 application.

Now I have registered the tlb/dll files on my computer and I am able to create an instance of the class in vb6 with

```
Dim c As New Advantage_Dealer_Email_CoreClassLibrary.CoreClass
```

However I want to use CreateObject(Class) but when I try I get the ActiveX error, here is the code I am using for that

```
Dim c As Object
Set c = CreateObject("Advantage.Dealer.Email.CoreClassLibrary.CoreClass")
```

Is this possible what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**Update**:
After searching through the registry I am only able to find a CLSID which references Advantage.Dealer.Email.CoreClassLibrary.

```
{CFB8F7A1-BC6F-4771-839F-1343785ED9D6} > 1.0 > (Default) REG_SZ Advantage.Dealer.Email.CoreClassLibrary
```

**Solution**

I had another look in the registry and found a Guid called

```
CoreClassInterface
```

which referenced the library, when I used the code

```
CreateObject("CoreClassInterface")
```

the vb6 program worked.

For anyone that comes across this post in the future it was because I had set the ProgID in the vb.net class when setting up the class with an interface for the Com Interop.

```
<Guid("7EB55A33-34E7-4FC4-A87B-41635EEAF32D"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ProgId("CommClassInterface")> Public Class CoreClass : Implements _CoreClassInterface
```

After removing the ProgID for the class and rebuilding/registering the library on my computer I found

```
Advantage.Dealer.Email.CoreClassLibrary.CoreClass
```

In the Registry, and my vb6 app worked.

Thanks for your help **tcarvin**

Comment: possible duplicate of [import vb.net class library to vb6 project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562819/import-vb-net-class-library-to-vb6-project)

Comment: Not really, the OP of that post was getting a completely different error, even when dimming.  I can successfully create a dim of the class it's when I try to do the same using 'CreateObject'

Comment: You should find the GUID under HKCR\CLSID, and under that GUID you should see other keys for InprocServer, ProgId, and more.  Likewise, your ProgId (used by CreateObject) should be in HKCR and should point to the GUID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it best, when creating .NET libraries for consumption by VB6, to keep the namespace of COM-visible classes to only one-layer deep to avoid the underscores.  Anyway, have you attempted to use:

```
CreateObject("Advantage_Dealer_Email_CoreClassLibrary.CoreClass")
```

When all else fails, the answer is in your registry.  Use regedit and see what the component is listed under.

Comment: I have tried using CreateObject("Advantage_Dealer_Email_CoreClassLibrary.CoreClass") with the same result

Also I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for in the registry, do you have an example?

Comment: Search within HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for CoreClass.  you would typically see it in a ProjectName.ClassName or PackageName.Classname format.  When you use `CreateObject`, it is doing a lookup in the registry.  If you find it, post the details to your question as and edit so we can review.

Comment: What did you use for your ClassInterface attribute on your com-visible class?

Comment: Did you try to explicitly set your programmatic ID via ProgId attribute?  Try a namespace and assembly name with no dots "." in it, register it, and repeat the search via regedit and see if you have more success.